# How do I create a patch file in windows?

Tags: windows, patch

I use windows 8 and have source codes of a software in English version. 
I translated it and want to create a patch file of it. It's my first time doing it..
And.. can I use diff which I believe can be used in Linux?

Comment: If you're trying to i18n (internationalize) some code, it's better to adapt it to use GNU gettext or the like so you don't patch over one language with another.  In any event, what language are you using...your question is hopelessly vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

winmerge can create patches is you are looking for a gui way. they have some hints for doing it scripted as well: http://manual.winmerge.org/Faq.html#d0e10357